# Ubuntu doesn't see my SATA SSD

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, sata, ahci

I have an Acer A317 laptop and a SATA Samsung EVO SSD.

UEFI sees the SATA SSD.

Only have UEFI legacy isn't an option. Secure boot is turned off...

Tried setting a admin/bios password to "unlock" extra settings but still no legacy or anything else.

No option in the UEFI settings to change sata mode and it's reporting as AHCI mode in Linux and windows. Checked the Samsung SSD in windows with magician to make sure it's not setup with turbo mode, encryption or and other oddities.

(Was able to find SATA mode in UEFI on main tab by hitting Ctrl+s to enable the hidden setting)

Windows bootable install media sees the SSD.

I ran clean on the drive to remove all partitions.

Ubuntu doesn't see the SSD.
Ran `lspci -k | grep SATA` and I get:

```
controller: Intel corporation ice lake-lp SATA controller [AHCI Mode]
```

Running `df -h` I cannot see the drive.

Gparted doesn't see the drive.

---

**Edit**: I got Ubuntu to detect the drive but it won't boot it.

Load up live USB. Check gparted not there. Suspend laptop, wake up, drive is there. Installer runs and installs to drive.

Reboot

Try to boot the SSD installed OS. And it "boots" as in grub loads and I hit enter on Ubuntu. After a few seconds of splash screen and loading circle. I get dropped to a Command line saying UUID doesn't exist (assume it's the SSD)

[image: cmdline after starting to boot]

Comment: Check the drive mode in UEFI ("BIOS") as it must be AHCI, other modes aren't (yet) compatible with Linux. Caveat: Windows installed in the original mode WON'T boot in AHCI unless AHCI support has been installed, something you must do if you want to dual-boot. If this is TMI for you then use Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Comment: No option in bios to change sata mode, just enable/disable the controller. And no legacy mode. UEFI only. Secure boot is off... Linux in lspci is reporting AHCI Mode.

Comment: https://community.acer.com/en/kb/articles/13993-how-to-change-sata-mode-to-ahci

Comment: I found that setting and it was in AHCI mode not the raid optane thing. Still doesn't fix my issue.